# Receive data from html tag with Java in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following html tag and I want to receive `"name":"test_1476979972086"` from my `Java Selenium` code.

How can I achive this?

I already tried `getText` and `getAttribute` function but without any success.

```
<a data-ng-href="#/devices" 
    target="_blank" 
    class="ng-binding" 
    href="#/devices">  
{"name":"test_1476979972086"}    
</a>
```

`getText()` is always emtpy. The xpath is unique. `newDevice.created` is unique on page.

```
final By successMessageBy = By.xpath("//p[@data-ng-show='newDevice.created']/a");

final WebElement successMessage = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(successMessageBy));

final String msg = successMessage.getText();
```

Comment: What do you mean without any success.?? Is there any exception?? And share how did you tried as well??

Comment: edited...see above

Comment: Is this element text visible on the page??

Comment: Update the html one level up ie the p tag...

Comment: And try once as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(successMessageBy)).getText();` and let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [`WebElement#getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) returns only visible text. It could be possible element is present there but text would be visible later.

So if [`WebElement#getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) doesn't work as expected, you should try using `getAttribute("textContent")` as below:-

```
successMessage.getAttribute("textContent");
```

Comment: That worked! Right element is not visible but present! :)

Answer (score 0):

upon first glance, the below should work. the fact that what you've tried doesnt work, leads me to believe that you aren't selecting the correct element. since i am ignorant of the rest of your html, this might not be unique. you'll have to play around with it, or share the surrounding html

```
String json = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href$='/devices']")).getText()
```

Comment: The selector is unique but getText returns an empty string.

Comment: @gartenkralle I copied the HTML and the code from the answer above and got the text....

Comment: interesting...I'm not.

Comment: then something else is going on.  you'll have to show more context for the element.  also, is that element you are sharing - is it from inspect element? or view page source? i ask this last question because the source is probably different than the actual because of all of the DHTML

Comment: It's from view page source.

Comment: I have a breakpoint at getText line and the html is still there.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from the inspect element from the surrounding p tag that you are using in the xpath...